# How to use Form data received from a POST request in Blazor pages?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor page that can receive form-data from a POST request. After this data is received, it will be set to two properties and also rendered onto the page. The problem is that after this has happened, the page will re-rendered and the data of the properties will be discarded.
Does somebody know why this is happening and what the best way is to keep my POST data, or stop the page from re-rendering?

I am currently using Blazor Server .net 6. I have already tried changing the render-mode from "ServerPrerendered" to "Server", but that doesn't solve the problem. Changing the render-mode to "Static" does prevent Blazor from re-rendering the page, but I don’t want to have static pages.

Here is my _Host.cshtml:

```
@page "/"
@namespace PostToRazorPageTest.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

@attribute [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]

@model HostPageModel
```

Here you can see the HostPageModel class, which I use to catch the form-data. It uses a PostFormService, which is a scoped service with one property that contains de Form data. Changing it to a Singleton does prevent the POST data from being discarded, but also forms a big privacy risk.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using PostToRazorPageTest.Services;

namespace PostToRazorPageTest.Pages
{
    public class HostPageModel : PageModel
    {
        // postFormService is injected by the DI
        public HostPageModel(PostFormService postFormService)
        {
            PostFormService = postFormService;
        }

        private PostFormService PostFormService { get; }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            // store the post form in the PostFormService
            PostFormService.Form = Request.Form;
        }

    }
}
```

The razor page where I read the form-data:

```
@page "/showdata"
@inject PostFormService PostFormService;

<PageTitle>Show POST data</PageTitle>

<h1>Show POST data</h1>

@if (Field1 != null && Field2 != null)
{
    <p>Field 1 value: @Field1</p>
    <p>Field 2 value: @Field2</p>
}
else
{
    <p>
        <b>
        The request wasn't made with a POST request, or the request was missing data for the field called "field1" and/or "field2".
        </b>
    </p>
}

@code {
    private string? Field1 { get; set; }
    private string? Field2 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        if (PostFormService.Form != null)
        {
            Field1 = PostFormService.Form["field1"];
            Field2 = PostFormService.Form["field2"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The DI scope you are using when you process the form data and store it is not the same scope the Blazor components use. You can pass the data to the `App` component by defining a suitable parameter on the `App` component and using the `param-...` notation on the `component` tag helper. Then inside the `App` you can inject a scoped instance of your form data service and store the data from the parameter into it.

Comment: @MisterMagoo Thank you for you answer, but I don't really get it. Which data/object must I pass to App.razor? Also, how do I use/access the data in my showdata.razor page, once it has been stored in App.razor?

Comment: You are posting a page to the Web Server.  It consumes the posted data and returns a prerendered web page that then starts the Blazor Server SPA.  You need to read the posted data server side and then pass the posted data to the Blazor page you are loading, or say save it in a singleton service that both the server side code and Blazor Hub code can see.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis But how do I keep my form data without using a singleton? The problem with a singleton is that other users will be able to see the posted form data.

Comment: @chris - see my "Answer" below for some example code that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a comment rather than a complete answer: I can't put example code into a comment!

You can do something like this with your service to make the request unique, and then pass the Guid - probably as a string into `App`.

```
public class DataService
{
    private Dictionary<Guid, FormData> _formData = new Dictionary<Guid, FormData>(); 

    public Guid AddFormData(FormData data)
    {
        var id = Guid.NewGuid();
        _formData.Add(id, data);
        this.ClearData();
        return id;
    }

    public bool TryGetFormData(Guid guid, out FormData data)
    {
        data = _formData[guid];
        this.ClearData();
        return data != null;
    }
    
    // clears old data
    private void ClearData()
    {
        var list = _formData.Where(item => item.Value.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(5) <= DateTime.Now).ToList();
        list.ForEach(item => _formData.Remove(item.Key));
    }

}

// example form data class
public class FormData
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

You can pass parameters into `App.razor` in _Host,html like this:

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<BlazorApp2.App>( RenderMode.ServerPrerendered,new {FormGuid="1234"}))
@*<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />*@
```

You can then have a scoped service to hold the form data:

```
// Set up as Scoped i.e. one per user session
public class MyFormDataService
{
    private readonly DataService dataService;

    public FormData? FormData { get; private set }

    public MyFormDataService(DataService dataService)
        => this.dataService = dataService;

    public void GetFormData(Guid id)
    {
        if (dataService.TryGetFormData(id, out FormData data))
            this.FormData = data;
    }
}
```

And load the service in `App`

```
@inject MyFormDataService dataService
<div>@this.FormGuid</div>
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code{
    [Parameter] public Guid FormGuid { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        =>  this.dataService.GetFormData(FormGuid);
}
```

And consume it wherever by injecting the DI instance of `MyFormDataService`.

Comment: I implemented your code and made a few changes and I have it now working! My only remaining question is as follows: how can a razor page access the Guid from App.razor?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Didn't think about creating a separate scoped service for delivering the data. Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: NP - one of my design adages is Data = Service.