# how to handle call back in in WASM?

Tags: callback, blazor

When the client is on my apps' shopping cart page and clicks on payment, he is redirected to an external site handling the payment.  The external site  sends back a post request to my Blazor (.razor) page .
MrC aka Shaun Curtis answered  the server side solution but I'm looking for WASM (client side web assembly) solution.
Thanks, siamak

getting posted data in client side page in WASM

Comment: HTTP POST is a method of sending requests to a server. Blazor WASM is a client side technology that is executed in the browser. You can't listen for a POST request in a Blazor WASM application.

Comment: I know  the difference between server side and client side blazor , what I am really looking for is a practical solution to get posted data from payment gate back to client .

Answer (score 0):

You will still need server-side code to listen for the post back - you cannot use WASM alone to process the HTTP post back.

Maybe you should read more as to the hosting models that Blazor WASM [actually supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-7.0#blazor-webassembly).

> When a standalone Blazor WebAssembly app uses a backend ASP.NET Core app to serve its files, the app is called a hosted Blazor WebAssembly app. Using hosted Blazor WebAssembly, you get a full-stack web development experience with .NET, including the ability to share code between the client and server apps, support for prerendering, and integration with MVC and Razor Pages. **A hosted client app can interact with its backend server app over the network using a variety of messaging frameworks and protocols, such as web API, gRPC-web, and SignalR (Use ASP.NET Core SignalR with Blazor).**

Blazor WASM on its own is a client-only execution tech - however, you can update the state of a Blazor WASM-app using SignalR (by coupling the WASM app with a .NET server backend) - this backend processes the post back and then uses SignalrR that the Blazor WASM app can listen to update it's state in response.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know the difference between client and server side blazor architecture .I am looking for a practical solution for client side... as  Shaun Curtis answered for  server side [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72147911/how-to-use-form-data-received-from-a-post-request-in-blazor-pages)

Comment: @siamakdanesh Respectfully I don't think you do understand if you think there exists a practical solution for 'client side'. What you are asking for is not possible with just Blazor WASM alone. If the front end is a WASM app, you need a server side backend to process the post back request - i.e. you need both. Maybe you should clarify your requirements further - perhaps you've worded your original question inelegantly.

Comment: dear sir there is certainly  a backend server ( web assembly hosted model ). WASM alone is useless. so there is blazor WASM and   hosted server ready to cooperate.

Comment: when payment gate redirects back, a new fresh connection starts throw client's browser and  blazor hosted server and request goes down  throw server pipeline, now server checks type of  the endpoint  a page or a web service. As data in my case is in posted form  , the end point a web service controller can extract the posted data, now if  find a way  redirect to a page inside the controller , server returns an appropriate  page ( result of transaction ) to client. I must check it ( i didn't try it by now ) .

Comment: so assuming a back end server is ready to answer requests , any suggestion is welcomed

Comment: @siamakdanesh all these details that you've posted as comments SHOULD BE IN YOUR QUESTION, including the link to the other answer you referred to. Your original question ended in *'but I'm looking for WASM (client side web assembly) solution...getting posted data in client side page in WASM'*. If you want people to help you, you need to provide as much detail as possible, and also post code of attempted solutions you've tried yourself. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you for your reply. I think with all these comments the main question must be obvious by now.   I will  post a new question with new title  **How to implement IPG payment callback in blazor web assembly?**  I googled with this new title and found  something close to my guess (  redirect in server API ) [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1164776/blazor-webassembly-shows-405-error-in-localhost-(a?orderby=newest) and at last than you for your attention.